# Symfony2/Doctrine: load only subset of related entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

A Symfony2 application has a `Job` entity which has a `tasks` property, a collection of `Task` entities.

`Job->getTasks()` is used to iterate over a given job's collection of tasks. The `Task` entities encapsulated in the `tasks` property are lazy-loaded by Doctrine. I'm guessing they're loaded at the point `getTasks()` is called.

With extra details removed, the `Job` entity looks something like this:

```
<?php

class Job
{        
    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Example\Bundle\Entity\Task\Task", mappedBy="job")
     */
    private $tasks;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->tasks = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getTasks()
    {        
        return $this->tasks;
    }
}
```

I often need to access only a subset of all tasks (maybe 10 out of 1000) for a job and currently do so by iterating over `getTasks()` and picking out those with relevant ids.

For large collections of tasks (thousands, tens of thousands) it can take a long time for the tasks collection to be loaded from the database.

I'd like to reduce the time required to gain access to a subset of tasks. I can do so by using a custom entity repository to retrieve `Task` entities by id and job.

I'd like to know if a in-built feature of Symfony2 and/or Doctrine2 already exists for doing this.

My thinking is that an entity with a related collection of entities is a common situation (blog post and comments, for example) and that there may be some pagination-related concept at the entity level for retrieving only a subset of related entities.

Is there an in-built Symfony2 feature for what I need?

**Update1:**

I'd ideally like to be able to still iterate over `Job->getTasks()` knowing that it will return only a subset of tasks that I have somehow specified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for [Extra Lazy Association](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html).

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. The name of the association itself sounds like it's heading in the right direction.

Comment: The Extra Lazy Association is certainly a valuable feature but this doesn't I don't believe this allows me to indicate which subset of `Task` entities to load up when iterating over `Job->getTasks()`. It's a neat aspect but I don't think it answers my question.

Comment: Well in that case you can create a wrapper around `Collection#slice($offset, $length = null);` method as the doc states that collection will only load entities defined in `slice()` boundaries.